# E: Error: BrokenCount > Orun-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available exited with return code 255

Tags: ubuntu, boot

When I got an upgrade request to 16.04 I tried to upgrade it. But after upgrade system restarted and booting started. At the end they asked for login id and password.

I entered it and after that this instructions displayed on screen that...

```
Last login: wed aug 1 10:55: 23 IST 2018 on tty1
E: Error: BrokenCount > Orun-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available exited with return code 255
```

How can I solve it?

Is it possible to downgrade 16.04 to 14.04?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:
*sudo dpkg --configure -a*

This should complete your update and your system should be back up after a reboot. If the above gives errors of broken packages, issue the below command:
*sudo apt-get install -f*

And then run the above command again.